# How does Android's setOnCLickListener() works?

Tags: java, android

I wonder how Android OnClik Listener works? What Pattern is it? Observer?

I cant imagine how I can Implement it in my App! It needs to be a custom implementation because I want to do it with my Objects not with views.

So how can I achieve to call obj.setOnClickListener(new Class(){});

in my code?

I mean ok I could have a methode in my baseclass from which the derived classes implement and then just havin a static ArrayList or so. But how can I add new Classes to this List at runtime?

The definiton of this class OnClickListener(){} is strange.

How is it possible to define an existing class and overriding a method?

My Java is not that good never done this...

EDIT: THIS QUESTION IS NOT ABOUT HOW TO USE ONCLICKLISTENER. I KNOW HOW TO USE THAT...

What i want:

I want a Super Class having an implementation of a method like this:

```
public void setMyOnclickListener(MyOnClickListener myListener)
{
    //magic code
}
```

and now I want to have an Object of this class lets call it

```
Subclass obj;
```

and now I want to do this:

```
obj.setMyOnClickLister(new MyOnClickListener()
    {
        //defined method at runtime
        public void aDefinedMethod()
        {
            //here goes in some code
        }
    });
```

how can I have a method with a class as a parameter which only exist as an anonymous class?

EDIT2:

Ok I get it OnClickListener is just an Interface -.- not a class defintion
That was my confusion!!!

Comment: how do u click if its not a view?, can u post a sample code regarding this so it will be easy to understand.

Comment: OnClickListeners are for view, what is that you actually try to achieve

Comment: I want to send out an signal in my list where I put my objects in, but I want like in Android to let the User of my framework to decide what action should be taken when this item is clicked. Just like normal Observer Pattern but the body of the method that should be executed by the observable should be declared when setting the listener

Comment: Also your listview has an onItemClicked method. Inside you can decide what should happen, if the user clicks on an entry.

Comment: -.- what listview? why are you commenting?

Comment: if you know the concept of interface and how Event Listener are implemented in java...then you would have probably understood how the onClick works

Comment: ok then check this link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html  and if you have still doubt you can ask...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each View contains `ListenerInfo` static class which holds callbacks, `OnClickListener` too actually.

## How it works?

System always holds all views on screen.
When user tap on screen we have a recursive foreach cycle :

```
switch(event) {
    ...
    case ON_CLICK:
    process(ViewRoot);
}

void process(View view) {
    
    for(View view : view.getChilds()) {
        if(view instanceOf ViewGroup && ((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount() > 0) {
             process(view);
        }
        if(view.getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener != null)
             view.getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener.onClick(view)
    }
}
```

When you call `setOnClickListener` you actually say *"hey Android! here it callback. And when user make click, please use it."*

**View.class** also have `getListenerInfo` method which returns `ListenerInfo` object.

System use this method to dispatch events.

So no `Observer` pattern here. It just simple check of existing callback.

Comment: Im gonna trust you thanks. I studied the source code also some minutes ago and also saw no Pattern. Ok I see its just another kind of structural pattern but it really looked like observer pattern, because events and listener sounds like observer

Comment: @IljaKO yes, u are right. For the first time i think same.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize your object (button) first

```
public class SomeActivity {
  ...
  private Button subButton1, subButton2;
  ...

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
        subButton1 = (Subclass) findViewById(R.id.home_button1);
        subButton2 = (Subclass) findViewById(R.id.home_button2);
  }
```

// next is the onClickListener

```
  private void init() {
    ...
        subButton1.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void myOnClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Your own on click 1");
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Your own on click 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        subButton2.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void myOnClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Your own on click 2");
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Your own on click 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
  }

  private void methodCall() {
    // some more code...
  }
```

// Subclass

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by roelsuntjens on 01-10-15.
 */
public class Subclass extends Button {
    public Subclass(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Subclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Subclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public Subclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(MyOnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(l);
    }
}
```

// MyOnClickListener

```
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by roelsuntjens on 01-10-15.
 */
public abstract class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    public MyOnClickListener() {
    }

    public abstract void myOnClick(View v);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myOnClick(v);
    }
}
```

// In XML I used this:

```
        <View3D.Subclass
            android:id="@+id/home_button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View3D.Subclass
            android:id="@+id/home_button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: youre trying to tell me how to use an onclicklistener? did you read the question?

Answer (score -1):

You can implement onClickListener like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771902/how-to-implement-onclicklistener-on-android) by implementing interface OnClickListener.
Set to your button on setOnClickListner(this) in your activity will listening the click event on the onClick method.

You can also create your on listener by declaring a private OnClickListener like that :

```
private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Click occurs, do something
    }
};
```

Then set button.setOnClickListener(listener);

Comment: why you want to tell me how to use an onclicklistener from androids framework? -I want my own!!!

Comment: I'm sorry... but i see that others users explain you the same thing so maybe your initial question wasn't so explicit

Comment: its ok...i updated the question but still problem is there hwo to achieve the functionality in my class heirarchies

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy...just in your activity_main.xml layout create a button
like this

```
          <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTake"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
//  android:onClick="onClick" (It will automatically create the method if u use onclic)//
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     />
```

Now just call the button with its id(IF u r not writing android:onClick="onClick" )

now in Main Activity do this

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     btnTack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePic);
     btnTack.setOnClickListener(this);
```

//call intent or do what u want

Now do what ever you want to do..

Comment: No! Thats not what I want! I know how to inflate View I know how to set onclicklistener and I know how to do Android programming. read the question gain pls