# performClick() produces StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

Currently developing a Tictactoe game for Android. The player vs player activity works perfectly, when I click a button it will show either 'X' or 'O' with a code like this:

```
if (player1Turn) {
        ((Button) v).setText("x");
    } else {
        ((Button) v).setText("o");
    }
```

Then I added the Minimax for player vs computer activity, the AI works perfectly too as it suggest the right move to outplay the opponent. The problem is, the AI can't self-click the button. I added `performClick()` to call the view's `onClickListener` but it doesn't work and produces `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. This is the code snippet:

```
if (player1Turn) {
        if (roundCount == 0) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randPointerOne = random.nextInt(3);
            int randPointerTwo = random.nextInt(3);
            buttons[randPointerOne][randPointerTwo].performClick();
            buttons[randPointerOne][randPointerTwo].setText("x");
            board[randPointerOne][randPointerTwo] = 'x';
        } else {
            minimax.setBoard(board);
            buttons[minimax.bestMoveRow][minimax.bestMoveCol].performClick();
            buttons[minimax.bestMoveRow][minimax.bestMoveCol].setText("x");
            board[minimax.bestMoveRow][minimax.bestMoveCol] = 'x';
        }

        //AI Suggestion for the next move in form of Text
        tvAI.setText(minimax.bestMoveRow + "R" + " " + minimax.bestMoveCol + "C");
```

I already defined the `setOnClickListener` on the `onCreate()` (as the official documentation says) like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            String buttonID = "button_"+ i + j;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
            buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
            buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
```

For additional information, if I removed the `performClick()` on the code, it will not produces the error but the AI still can't self-click and will only generate the 'X' or 'O' if I clicked one of the buttons for the AI (and of course, when it's AI turn to move).

If I doing it wrong, what is the right implementation of the `performClick()` to do an AI self-click? Is there an alternative way too? Thank you for reading the whole question btw! :)

Comment: This error occurs due to an infinite loop.

Comment: It's hard to tell with the code you've posted but my guess is that performing a click triggers the AI calculation and that means `performClick()` just calls the entire block of code again. Setting `player1Turn` to `false` before that call might help (it would also help if you'd post the relevant part of the stack trace you get). But having the AI actually click a button is bad design anyway. You should create a "background" model of the game which the AI operates on and the UI (and thus buttons) are only a view of that model (have a look at the MVC pattern).

Comment: Check out this, [How Click Listener Works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884665/how-does-androids-setonclicklistener-works)