# Change Button Visibility

Tags: android

**My onClick() method:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        String Adm = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
        EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        if (Adm.equals("Administrator")){
            t1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

**My layout.xml:**

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Administrator"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

So basically I have 2 Buttons and what I want to do is call ClickEvent to change the visibility of the EditText fields. I'm new to this so I'm trying my best but still something is missing.

Relevant code above.

Comment: Exactly what is wrong?

Comment: When I press the Button nothing happends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your button xml like this:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Administrator"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

`android:onClick="onClick"` will attach a `ClickListener` to your button and `onClick` from activity will get called.

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771902/how-to-implement-onclicklistener-on-android) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was missing!. I'll mark this as correct Answer.

Answer (score 0):

`android:visibility="invisible"` should be   `android:visibility="Gone"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your button invisible, but keep taking space on the screen, use
 `android:visibility="invisible"` and if you want your button to disappear completely - use `android:visibility="gone"`